# Question on preposition

Tags: prepositions

Do you say

1) get some food to go from the Italian restaurant

OR

2) get some food to go at the Italian restaurant

or both are Okay?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U! This question appears to be more suitable for [the English Language Users stack exchange](https://ell.stackexchange.com/), please ask your question there. It may be difficult to understand your question, please add more information on what your sentence should mean. Are you getting take-away food from an Italian restaurant or bringing food to an Italian restaurant?

Comment: Thank you for your reply.Next time I'll use the exchange forum.  I meant " getting take-away food from the Italian restaurant ( that the other person knows about).

Comment: *Both* sentences are grammatical. Although the first is more common, there's nothing actually wrong with the second.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The first sentence is grammatically correct (get ... from ...) because 'food to go' is an idiom.
For example:
I'd like to order some food to go.
So we can get smth FROM...
(Compare: We often have our business lunch AT the nearest Italian restaurant. )